# Querying Sql Server 2005 with bit data type column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

This doesn't work with sql server 2005

```
select * from [mytablename] where [mybitcolumn] <> 1
```

and I had to use...

```
select * from [mytablename] where (([mybitcolumn] is null) or ([mybitcolumn]=0))
```

Is there alternative syntax that that would get rows where mybitcolum <> 1?

Comment: What is wrong with using two conditions?

Comment: Maybe don't allow NULL in the column?

Comment: Andriy M: I don't have DML access on the data and there where no zero/false values to test if the two conditions actually worked.  I ended up making a table I could manipulate the data to test it and it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select * from [mytablename] where isnull([mybitcolumn], 0) = 0
```

Although it's only marginally better.

Alternatively, and I'm hesitant to suggest it, you turn off `ANSI NULLS`.  For instance:

```
set ansi_nulls on
go

if (1 != null)
    print 'This will not print equal because NULL is a third boolean value.'

set ansi_nulls off
go

if (1 != null)
    print 'Not equal since we told SQL Server to treat null as any other value'
```

Also have a look at [Three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

Comment: @Yuck...where isnull(mybitcolumn,'False') = 'False' AND ...where isnull(mybitcolumn,0) = 0 both do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Since `1` is considered as `true`; With `where [mybitcolumn] <> 1` you are trying to get `false` scenario. what if you try like below

```
select * from [mytablename] where [mybitcolumn] = 'false'
```

If in case `mybitcolumn` contains `NULL` then you can use `ISNULL` function

```
select * from [mytablename] where ISNULL([mybitcolumn],0) = 'false'
```

Comment: Since the OP is clearly having problems due to null values in mybitcolumn, your answer will fail.

Comment: The OP wants to catch NULLs and 0s with a single condition. Your suggestion would catch only 0s.

Comment: @Rahul - your last suggestion was close.  I found both of the following worked: ...where isnull(mybitcolumn,'False') = 'False' AND ...where isnull(mybitcolumn,0) = 0